# Make context menu appear on top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

**OK, so, here's my setup:**

- I have a jQuery [UI Layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.com/) setup (one west, one south, and a center panel)
- In the west panel, there is a [jqTree](http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree) (with the [jqTreeContextMenu](http://daviduv.github.io/jqTreeContextMenu/) plugin, showing a simple dropdown menu, on right click)

**The issue:**

When the user right clicks on any of the tree items, the context menu *does* appear, although it appears sort of "clipped", while it should appear ON TOP of everything, no matter what.

I've played a bit with the `z-index`s but - as usual, since it's not actually my... thing - I cannot get it to work.

So, any ideas?

---

**Live demo:** `http://testbox.drkameleon.com/peppermint/uilayout.html`

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/2ke92qcg/

*(the layout here, for some reason, appears rather weird, but it shouldn't matter. Closing and re-opening the west panel fixes the issue)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK...

So, after a lot of trial-and-error, here it is:

```
.ui-layout-west{
    z-index: 5000 !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

And that was all! :-)

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned before

z-index only works within a particular context i.e. relative, fixed or absolute position.

z-index for a relative div has nothing to do with the z-index of an absolutely or fixed div.

[Here is your FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/erenyener/2ke92qcg/2/)

```
ul#filetreeMenu {
    z-index: 999 !important;
    position: fixed;
}

div#wrapper {
    position: initial !important;
}
```